# Get query line and file where it was built in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, logging

In my project, i want to log the location of query build for debug. I try this:

```
if (!empty(env('ENABLE_QUERY_LOGGER'))) {
            DB::listen(function ($query) {
                $formatQuery = str_replace(array('?'), array('\'%s\''), $query->sql);
                $formatQuery = strtoupper(vsprintf($formatQuery, $query->bindings));

                // Get the caller's file and line
                $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);
                $caller = isset($trace[1]) ? $trace[1] : [];

                // Query time in milliseconds
                $loggerInfo = 'QUERY EXECUTED: ' . $formatQuery
                    . ' || TIME EXECUTED: ' . ($query->time / 1000) . 's'
                    . ' || DB CONNECTION: ' . $query->connectionName
                    . ' || FILE: ' . ($caller['file'] ?? 'Unknown')
                    . ' || LINE: ' . ($caller['line'] ?? 'Unknown');

                Log::info($loggerInfo);
            });
        }
```

But it throw this log:

```
[2023-08-25 07:20:15] local.INFO: QUERY EXECUTED: SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `ID` = '12' LIMIT 1 || TIME EXECUTED: 0.00321s || DB CONNECTION: mysql || FILE: C:\Users\ACER\Documents\PHP\learn_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php || LINE: 249  
[2023-08-25 07:20:15] local.INFO: QUERY EXECUTED: SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `ID` = '12' LIMIT 1 || TIME EXECUTED: 0.00081s || DB CONNECTION: mysql || FILE: C:\Users\ACER\Documents\PHP\learn_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php || LINE: 249  
[2023-08-25 07:20:15] local.INFO: QUERY EXECUTED: SELECT `ID` FROM `SHOP` WHERE `USER_ID` = '12' LIMIT 1 || TIME EXECUTED: 0.00087s || DB CONNECTION: mysql || FILE: C:\Users\ACER\Documents\PHP\learn_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php || LINE: 249  
[2023-08-25 07:20:15] local.INFO: QUERY EXECUTED: SELECT * FROM `STAFF` WHERE `SHOP_ID` = '11' || TIME EXECUTED: 0.00085s || DB CONNECTION: mysql || FILE: C:\Users\ACER\Documents\PHP\learn_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php || LINE: 249
```

It even not my edited file.

How can i do for my purpose?

Comment: Events are dispatched by the dispatcher and handled by your handler. Logically whatever called the dispatcher would probably be the query builder and you want the file that called the query builder which I guess would be index 4 in the trace. Note that this may not always be the case, the more "foolproof" way is to show the first entry in your trace from a file that is not inside `vendor` meaning it's your own file